# When ever I run my code this pops up : Event { isTrusted: [Getter] } what do i do?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

When ever I run this code:
https://replit.com/@CameronButcher/FlakyPurpleBundledsoftware#index.html
it spams

```
Event { isTrusted: [Getter] }
Event { isTrusted: [Getter] }
```

then it just says loading

Comment: I can't see your code. If you want us to answer, post the code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your folder `assets/spreadsheets` should have bee called `assets/spritesheets`. You were getting a bunch of 404 errors when preloading images. I'm not sure why p5.js was generating such unhelpful output in this case. You might want to update to the latest version of [p5.js (1.3.1)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p5).

The issue is now fixed in your Replit project.